# Find substring and replace with Null SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Available String :

`String1;#1;#String2;#233;#String3;#7;#string4`

I want to Results looks like following.
Results :

```
String1|String2|String3|string4
```

thanks

Comment: Probably the easiest way to deal with this is to use a string splitter. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Then use a where predicate to prevent unwanted return values.

Comment: What is the question? String available where? Is it a result of some query, or is it in a table, one column, stored like this......

Comment: Means I have Input "String1;#1;#String2;#233;#String3;#7;#string4" and i am looking for output "String1|String2|String3|string4"

Comment: Is this one row in the output or is that multiple rows? We can't read your mind here. You have got to post some details so we can help.

Comment: So you want split a string by a delimiter?

Comment: One row input and one row output

Answer (score 1):

As I said previously the quickest path here is to use a splitter. Then you will need to squish those results back into a single row. You can easily do this using FOR XML

You can a number of splitters here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings These tend to be the most popular around here. My personal choice is a little different. It has some limitations but also has some features (like ordinal row number) that most others splitters don't. You can find the article (and the code) for the splitter I used here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Here is the code to produce the desired output based on your sample data.

```
declare @StringToSplit varchar(500) = 'String1;#1;#String2;#233;#String3;#7;#string4'

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT '|' + REPLACE(Item, '#', '')
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@StringToSplit, ';')
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(replace(Item, '#', '')) = 0
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```